# Javascript: reload default after userscript

Tags: javascript, userscripts, event-listener, tampermonkey

I have a user script that does some stuff after clicking a button. By clicking the same button again (like a toggle button), I want it to 'revert' back to default. By default I mean the on page load content. Check my code:

```
var myTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0];
var myCells = myTbl.getElementsByTagName("td");

myCells[2].innerHTML = "<span id='myButton' class='button'>Do something / Revert</span>";

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

function doSomething() {
  // do some stuff with myTbl
  document.getElementById("myButton").removeEventListener("click", doSomething, false);
  document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", revertToDefault, false);
}

function revertToDefault() {
  // location.reaload();
}
```

I could do it with `location.reaload();`, but that's not what I want. I would prefer to save the default on load content in a variable like I did with the variable myTbl `var myTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0];` and preserve that default content and then simply save that default content in the variable myTbl `myTbl = defaultTbl;` when executing the `revertToDefault()` function. What's the correct code to do that? Is there a better way of doing that, perhaps without the need of saving everything in a variable?

Comment: It's hard to give an answer if you don't share all your code (HTML and CSS). Can you please add more?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter what happens in the rest of the code. In the `doSomething()` function I manipulate some table tags and innerHTML content. When I press the button the second time I just want the table to be as it was before the user script.

Comment: I save the table into my myTbl `var myTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0];` and defaultTbl `var defaultTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0];` variables. Then I manipulate the myTbl variable, but I want the defaultTbl variable to be intact, but if I manipulate myTbl, defaultTbl changes as well. I need a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

A possible working solution:

```
var myTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0];
var defaultTbl = myTbl.innerHTML; // this way defaultTbl remains intact while manipulating myTbl object

function revertToDefault() {
  myTbl.innerHTML = defaultTbl;
}
```